# How to extract keywords from Google search results page URL?

Tags: regex, r, url

One of the variables in my dataset contains URLs of Google search results pages. I want to extract the search keywords from those URLs.

An example dataset:

```
keyw <- structure(list(user = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("p1", "p2"), class = "factor"),
                   url = structure(c(3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("https://www.google.nl/search?q=five+fingers&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=kERoVbmMO6fp7AaGioCYAw", "https://www.google.nl/search?q=five+fingers&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=kERoVbmMO6fp7AaGioCYAw#safe=off&q=five+short+fingers+", "https://www.google.nl/search?q=high+five&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=bENoVZSqL4ON7Qb5wIDIDg", "https://www.google.nl/search?q=high+five&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=bENoVZSqL4ON7Qb5wIDIDg#safe=off&q=high+five+with+a+chair", "https://www.google.nl/search?q=high+five&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=bENoVZSqL4ON7Qb5wIDIDg#safe=off&q=high+five+with+handshake", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HOallAdtDI"), class = "factor")), 
              .Names = c("user", "url"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

So far I was able to extract the search keyword parts from the URLs with:

```
keyw$words <- sapply(str_extract_all(keyw$url, 'q=([^&#]*)'),paste, collapse=",")
```

However, this still doesn't give me the desired result. The above code gives the following result:

```
> keyw$words
[1] "q=high+five"                           
[2] "q=high+five,q=high+five+with+handshake"
[3] "q=high+five,q=high+five+with+a+chair"  
[4] "q=five+fingers"                        
[5] "q=five+fingers,q=five+short+fingers+"  
[6] ""
```

There are three problems with this output:

1. I only need the words as a string. Instead of `q=high+five`, I need `high,five`.
2. As rows 2, 3 & 5 show, the URL sometimes contains two parts with search keywords. As the first part is merely a reference to the previous search, I only need the second search query.
3. When the URL is not a Google search page URL, it should return an `NA`.

The desired result should be:

```
> keyw$words
[1] "high,five"                           
[2] "high,five,with,handshake"
[3] "high,five,with,a,chair"  
[4] "five,fingers"                        
[5] "five,short,fingers"
[6] NA
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another update after comment (looks too complex but it's the best I can achieve at this point :)):

```
keyw$words <- sapply(str_extract_all(str_extract(keyw$url,"https?:[/]{2}[^/]*google.*[/].*"),'(?<=q=|[+])([^$+#&]+)(?!.*q=)'),function(x) if(!length(x)) NA else paste(x,collapse=","))
> keyw$words
[1] "high,five"                "high,five,with,handshake" "high,five,with,a,chair"   "five,fingers"            
[5] "five,short,fingers"       NA
```

The change is the filter on input to str_extract_all, changed from the full vector by a "filtered" one to match a regex, any regex can go there to match more or less precisely what you wish.

Here the regex is:

- `http` litteraly http
- `s?` 0 or 1 s
- `[/]{2}` exactly two slashes (using a character class avoid needing the ugly `\\/` construction and get things more readable
- `[^/]*` any number of not slash  characters
- `google.*[/]` match litteraly google followed by anything to the last /
- `.*` finally match something or not after the last slash

Replace * by + wherever you want to ensure there's a parameter (`+` will require the preceding character to be present at least once)

---

Update heavily inspired by @BrodieG, will return NA if there's no match, but will still match any site if there's `q=` in the parameters.

Still with the same method:

```
> keyw$words <- sapply(str_extract_all(keyw$url,'(?:(?<=q=|\\+)([^$+#&]+)(?!.*q=))'),function(x) if(!length(x)) NA else paste(x,collapse=","))
> keyw$words
[1] "high,five"                "high,five,with,handshake" "high,five,with,a,chair"  
[4] "five,fingers"             "five,short,fingers"       NA
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tN1cU7/1)

(The lookbehind `(?<=)` ensure there's q= or + somewhere before the word and the the negative lookahead `(?!)` ensure we can't find q= untill the end of line.

The character class disallow the + sign to stop at each word.

Comment: very close, see also my updated question after testing it on my real data

Comment: @Jaap updated answer but I still wonder what you wish to get for something like `http://whatever.com/search?q=my+search+words` should it be `NA` or `my,search,words` ?

Comment: Interesting point. How would you formulate the regex if i wanted to give results from `http://whatever.com/search?q=my+search+words` an `NA` value?

Comment: @Jaap I see no way in pure regex. I'll try to update the answer with a two pass filter for this evolution later this day.

Comment: Much appreciated! For this specific problem, your answer gives me the desired result as there are only google-searchpages in my dataset. For the future I will certainly need a solution that can filter out specfic searches (e.g.: all Google-searches like `http://google.com/search?q=my+search+words` or all searches on a specific page like `http://whatever.com/search?q=my+search+words`)

Comment: @Jaap answer udpated.

Answer (score 8):

Or maybe this

```
gsub("\\+", ",", gsub(".*q=([^&#]*[^+&]).*", "\\1", keyw$url))
# [1] "high,five"                "high,five,with,handshake" "high,five,with,a,chair"  
# [4] "five,fingers"             "five,short,fingers"
```

Answer (score 5):

Update (borrowing part of the regex from David):

```
dat <- as.character(keyw$url)
pat <- "^https://www\\.google\\.nl/.*\\bq=([^&]*[^&+]).*"
sapply(
  regmatches(dat, regexec(pat, dat)),
  function(x) if(!length(x)) NA else gsub("\\+", ",", x[[2]])
)
```

Produces:

```
[1] "high,five"                "high,five,with,handshake" "high,five,with,a,chair"  
[4] "five,fingers"             "five,short,fingers"       NA
```

Using:

```
pat <- "^https://www\\.google.(?:com?.)?[a-z]{2,3}/.*\\b?q=([^&]*[^&+]).*"
```

takes into account all country specific google-domains ([source](http://www.powergrep.com/manual/xmpapachegoogle.html))

---

Or:

```
gsub("\\+", ",", sub("^.*\\bq=([^&]*).*", "\\1", keyw$url))
```

Produces:

```
[1] "high,five"                "high,five,with,handshake" "high,five,with,a,chair"  
[4] "five,fingers"             "five,short,fingers,"
```

Here we use greediness to make sure we skip everything up to the last `q=...` part, and then use the standard `sub` / `\\1` trick to capture what we want.  Finally, replace `+` with `,`.

Comment: Hmm.. This similar to what I've proposed in the chat room, but doesn't handle the `,` at the end

Comment: @DavidArenburg Wasn't in the chat room in past 10 minutes, and yes, good point about trailing comma.

Comment: Thanx, the trailing comma needs to be removed. See also my updated question about non-Google urls

Comment: @Jaap, no problem, though almost certainly it is because you have different google sites.  This just matches specifically to https://www.google.nl

Answer (score 3):

There's got to be a cleaner way, but maybe something like:

```
sapply(strsplit(keyw$words, "q="), function(x) {
  x <- if (length(x) == 2) x[2] else x[3]
  gsub("+", ",", gsub("\\+$", "", x), fixed = TRUE)
})
# [1] "high,five"                "high,five,with,handshake" "high,five,with,a,chair"  
# [4] "five,fingers"             "five,short,fingers"
```

Everything in one go:

```
keyw$words <- sapply(str_extract_all(keyw$url, 'q=([^&#]*)'),function(x) {
  x <- if (length(x) == 2) x[2] else x[1]
  x <- gsub("+", ",", gsub("\\+$", "", x), fixed = TRUE)
  gsub("q=","",x, fixed = TRUE)
})
```

Comment: Thanx. It works, but the other solutions are indeed cleaner. See also my updated question about nong-Google urls

Comment: @Jaap, if I'm not mistaken, my code will give you the `NA` you are expecting too--correct?

Comment: That's correct. I also included a integration solution in your answer (which could probably be improved). I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try with:

```
x<-as.character(keyw$url)
vapply(regmatches(x,gregexpr("(?<=q=)[^&]+",x,perl=TRUE)),
       function(y) paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(y,"\\+"))),collapse=","),"")
#[1] "high,five"                "high,five,with,handshake"
#[3] "high,five,with,a,chair"   "five,fingers"            
#[5] "five,fingers,short"
```